# Get a fully qualified name for references using scalameta

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scalameta

I'm trying to write a simple program to traverse all the referenced code starting from a given method using `scalameta`.

I was able to follow the calls but could not resolve method references.

**analyzeme/src/main/scala/codelab/FindMe.scala**

```
package codelab

object FindMe {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x = someRecognizeableName(1, 2)
    val y = List(1, 2, 3)
    y.foldLeft(0)(someRecognizeableName)
  }
  def someRecognizeableName(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
}
```

Generated and loaded semanticdb for `FindMe.scala` and checking the usages of `someRecognizeableName` method.

I can see the first call in the `db.names` list:

```
[87..108): someRecognizeableName => _root_.codelab.FindMe.someRecognizeableName(Int,Int).
```

The second one, though, when I don't call the method, just pass the reference is showing up as this:

```
[159..180): someRecognizeableName => local2_src_main_scala_codelab_FindMe_scala
```

So when I try to follow references startin from `main`, I don't get a fully qualified name of the `someRecognizeableName` reference in the second case.

## Question: Is there a way to get a fully qualified name from semanticdb for that reference?

---

---

### Full source to reproduce the above

**run instructions:**

```
analyzeme $ sbt compile
analyzer $ sbt "run ../analyzeme"
```

**analyzeme/src/main/scala/codelab/FindMe.scala**

```
package codelab

object FindMe {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x = someRecognizeableName(1, 2)
    val y = List(1, 2, 3)
    y.foldLeft(0)(someRecognizeableName)
  }
  def someRecognizeableName(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
}
```

**analyzer/src/main/scala/Main.scala**

```
import org.langmeta.io.{Classpath, Sourcepath}

import scala.meta._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    println(s"Loading from [${ args(0) }]")
    println()

    val cp = Classpath(s"${ args(0) }/target/scala-2.12/classes")
    val sp = Sourcepath(s"${ args(0) }/src/main/scala")

    val db = Database.load(cp, sp)

    println("* names:")
    db.names foreach println
    println()
    println("* symbols:")
    db.symbols foreach println
    println()
    println("* synthetics:")
    db.synthetics foreach println
    println()
    println("* messages:")
    db.messages foreach println
    println()
  }

}
```

**analyzeme/build.sbt**

```
name := "analyzee"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

addCompilerPlugin("org.scalameta" % "semanticdb-scalac" % "3.4.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
scalacOptions += "-Yrangepos"
```

**analyzer/build.sbt**

```
name := "analyzer"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % "3.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "contrib" % "3.4.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package codelab

object FindMe {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val x = someRecognizeableName(1, 2)

  y.foldLeft(0)(someRecognizeableName)
  // same as
  y.foldLeft(0){ a, b => someRecognizeableName(a, b) }
}
```

I debug the code and found at the second case, the compiler passed an anonymous symbol which is not accessible from the current semanticdb, it maybe should comes in the syhthetics partion but I can't find it inside.

So I guess the compiler generated anonymous is missing in the current semanticdb.